Setting path for a executable file in multiple directories
I have 10 directories in which I have to execute a compiled program. When running bash/LINUX, I use the following command
cd WORKING-DIRECTORY
./program-name control-file.ctl

To avoid using './', I use the following command
cd WORKING-DIRECTORY
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
program-name control-file.ctl

Now, for running my program in 10 directories, is it a good practice to run 'export PATH=$PATH:$PWD' every time I want to execute my program??. Or is there a better way to avoid to setting the path?.

You could just wrap the whole execution in a sub-shell and not let it propagate it outside, i.e. (cd WORKING-DIRECTORY; export PATH=$PATH:$PWD; program-name control-file.ctl; )

It makes the $PATH extra long in the longer run. It's possible to add '.' to your $PATH, by PATH+=:. but note that some people regard it insecure and it's definitely not recommended for the root user.

add that path to your PATH when you login - in .bashrc or .bash_profile at login. Ideally only have the executable you want in the path you've added (so as to avoid potential conflicts with other executables,shell scripts etc)

It's usually a better idea to use ./foo than add $PWD to your PATH and then run foo because if you add it to the end then if some other tool named foo exists in your PATH you'll execute that instead of the foo you want to execute. It also means any other command you call could now undesirably pick up a command from your local directory (more likely if you add $PWD to the front). If you need to call the foo command that's in your current directory then just call ./foo.

Do you really need to cd to the directory of the script? Why not just run $wdir/program-name $wdir/control-file.ctl?

Why do you have 10 directories with executables?  What is the directory structure? Why do you need to change the working directory to run a program? It's old school but  you could use stow to symlink those into 1 directory.  You also also write a wrapper script that given a command finds which of the directories it resides it and just execute it with a relative path or if you wish cd to the directory first.

To avoid using './' - please explain what problem you are trying to solve by doing this

you can also symlink to ~/bin and add only that to your PATH

To automatically run executables from the current directory without typing ./:
If you want to always have Bash search for executables in the Present Working Directory (PWD), you can add . to your PATH:
export PATH="$PATH:."

Add that to your login script, and it will always search in ., which is equivalent to how you used ./scriptname to run your script, wherein ./ specifies the current folder.

IMPORTANT WARNING:
If you add . to your PATH, then any file set executable in the current directory can be run without ./, which may cause you to accidentally run a script you didn't intend to.
Also, it is important to add . to the end of your path -- if it is placed at the start of PATH then Bash will search in the current folder before checking the normal system paths such as /bin or /usr/bin, which will cause a script in the current folder with the same name to override the system defaults (for example if there's a script called ls in the current folder, it would be run instead of /bin/ls).

Alternative #1:
You can just add all 10 folders to your PATH:
export PATH="$PATH:/folder1:/folder2:..."

There's no particular limit to how many search paths you can have.  As you add more and more search paths, it will make tab-completion take a bit longer, as it must scan all the files in each folder.

Alternative #2:
What most people do is create a personal scripts/programs folder that is in their search PATH, such as:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/jsmith/apps"

Then you can either place the scripts into that specific folder, or, add symlinks to your 10 scripts in that folder.

Relative vs. absolute paths:
Be aware that if a script is run from your PATH, the working directory will be whatever folder you ran the command from, not the directory where the Bash script is located.
If your script uses files from its own directory, you will need to make sure your script knows where to find these files.  This can be as simple as putting cd /folder2 at the top of the script to start it in the right place.
Alternatively, you can use the realpath and dirname commands to locate the folder where the script was run from automatically, then switch to it:
Script_File="$(realpath "$0")"
Script_Dir="$(dirname "$Script_File")"

cd "$Script_Dir" || {
   echo "Failed to switch to script directory."
   exit 1
}

